# synthetic and analytical forms (Subjunctive I and Subjunctive II)

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I would like to know how often one uses the synthetic form in English language (about synthetic form, for example, one may see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive).

Some example of the synthetic form:

> It is necessary that he/they BE here at 6 o’clock.
>
> She looks as if she WERE ill.
>
> They ordered that he COME.

1) How often is the synthetic form used in spoken language? Or more commonly to use the analytical form:

> It is necessary that he should go there at once.

2) How often is the synthetic form used in academic English?

3) May one meet the synthetic form in IELTS or TOEFL?

4) At the present time is synthetic form replaced analytical form?

Comment: Where did you get the names *synthetic* and *analytic* form? I haven't heard them before, and they don't make any sense to me.

Comment: The answer will be different, depending on whether you're asking about British or American English (and possibly, even what region of the countries you're asking about). Are you interested in one of these in particular?

Comment: And a little bit of nitpicking that is rather irrelevant to the question ... why would you use the subjunctive in *she looks as if she were ill*? If you say that, chances are that she ***is*** ill, so the situation is not hypothetical, and you use the indicative: *she looks as if she is ill* (or, in today's language, *she looks like she's ill*).

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps for some folks *as if* always triggers the unreal past?

Comment: @PeterShor You may read about synthetic and analytic form there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_typology

Comment: Maybe "she looks as if she were ill" is a bad example.

Comment: @PeterShor  I am interested British English as well as in American English

Comment: Illumintes, you seem to be saying that in the synthetic form it might be *necessary that he be here at 6 o’clock* and in the analytical - should that not be analytic? - that *he should go there at once*. Is that correct, please? Are you saying the difference lies in the word *should* or what, please?
If not in should then how are those phrases not interchangeable, please?